# Cannot find interface declaration for 'SenTestCase'

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, unit-testing

When I try to add another file to my testing target, it does not find the SenTestKit framework.

```
error: cannot find interface declaration for 'SenTestCase', superclass of 'RandomClassTests'
```

When I added the file I did check the Tests-target for this file, which seems like a gotcha for other people getting this error, but even when I added the files to the correct target I get this.

When I select the .m-file I see that it is added to the correct target, exactly as the main testing file you are provided with from start.

My new file appears under the "Compile Sources" phase under Build Phases for the testing target.
I cant find any other places to look for errors.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I do include the framework, the entire file looks like this:

```
#import <SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h>

@interface SituationAnalysisTests : SenTestCase

@end
```

**EDIT**
Also I'm running xcode 4.2 under Snow Leopard

Comment: What version number does Xcode state in its About window?

Comment: xcode 4.2, I'm under Snow Leopard

Answer (score 1):

Make sure in the .h file for your SenTestCase subclass, you do:

`#import <SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h>`